# Standard upload web control alternatives

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC application. There is little space for me to put two standard file uploading web controls in a page. So I'm seeking for some succinct alternatives. A checkbox-look button pops up a file open dialog is ideal. Is there any kind of stuff?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AjaxUpload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) control.
This will allow you to set almost anything as an upload control.